# Need help proving boundings of coefficients of Taylor series of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, boundary-value-problem

I have a hard time making the following type of exercises. I write down below some that I found:

> - Let $R$ be a real positive number, $f$ a holomorphic function in $D(0,R)$ with its Taylor series centered in $0$ being $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ for $|z|<R$. If $f$ verifies that $|f'(z)|\le 13$ for all $z\in D(0,R)$, then $|a_n|\le\frac{13}{nR^{n-1}}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.
> - Let $f$ be an entire function and let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be its Taylor series centered in $0$. Suppose that $|f(z)|\le 25e^{|z|}$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$. Prove that $|a_n|\le 25\left(\frac en\right)^{n}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.
> - Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the unit disc $\Bbb D = \{|z|<1\}$ which verifies $|f(z)|\le\frac{1}{1-|z|}$ for all $z\in\Bbb D$. If we consider $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ the Taylor series of $f$ centered in $0$, prove that $|a_n|\le e(n-1)$.

- In the first one, I did the derivative in both sides of the equality $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ and get
  \begin{equation}
  f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}\ge na_nz^{n-1}\text{ for any }n\in\Bbb N.
  \end{equation}
  Then,
  \begin{equation}
  n|a_n| |z|^{n-1}\le |f'(z)| \le 13 \Rightarrow |a_n|\le\frac{13}{n|z|^{n-1}}
  \end{equation}
  I don't know if I can take limits when $|z|\to R$ and get what we want. Is it correct?
- For the second one, we use that $a_n = \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$ and get
  \begin{equation}
  |a_n| = \left|\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|\le \frac1{2\pi} 2\pi R\max_{z\in Sop(\gamma_R)}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{n+1}}\le R\frac{25e^{|z|}}{|z|^{n+1}}
  \end{equation}
  The only way that I can think of getting what we need is to take $R=|z|=n$, but I don't know how correct it is either.
- I think this one might be similar to the previous one, but I can't seem to get to anything similar.

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first problem, the use of the inequality
$$
f'(z) \geq na_n z^{n-1}
$$
isn't correct. The sum is not always greater than the terms. You need to use
$$
na_n = \frac1{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{f'(z)}{z^n} dz\quad\mbox{for any  } r:\ 0<r<R
$$
and
$$
a_n \leq \frac1{n2\pi} \int\limits_{|z|=r} \frac1{r^n} |f'(z)| |dz| \leq
\frac1{n2\pi}2\pi r \frac{13}{r^n} = \frac{13}{nr^{n-1}}
$$
It is correct to take the limit $r\to R$ in the last inequality.

In the second problem, substitution $R = n$, $|z| = R$ is correct.

In the third problem, you need to use the same inequality as in the second problem:
$$
a_n \leq \frac1{2\pi} 2\pi R \max\limits_{|z| = R} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{n+1}} \leq \frac1{R^n}\frac1{1-R}\quad\mbox{for any } R:\ 0 < R < 1.
$$
Now it is natural to minimize the right-hand side of the last inequality for $R$. Substitution $R = \frac{n}{n+1}$ gives
$$
a_n \leq (n+1)\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^n.
$$

Comment: Wonderful! I wasn't able to get to that last substitution. Thank you so much!